# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when groupby list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataset

```
df =
value pattern
3     [1,0,0]
4     [1,0,0]
2     [1,0,1]
3     [1,0,1]
5     [1,0,1]
```

where the variable pattern is a list as we can see. I would like to aggregate and sum the value per list:

```
df_output = 
value pattern
7     [1,0,0]
10    [1,0,1]
```

I tried the following:

```
df_output = df.reset_index().groupby('pattern').count()
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any idea how to use groupby() with a combination of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to tuples and then back to lists in `rename`:

```
df_output = df.groupby(df['pattern'].apply(tuple)).sum().rename(list).reset_index()

print (df_output)
     pattern  value
0  [1, 0, 0]      7
1  [1, 0, 1]     10
```

Another idea is aggregate by tuples with `sum` and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df_output = (df.groupby(df['pattern'].apply(tuple))
               .agg({'value':'sum', 'pattern':'first'})
               .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df_output)
   value    pattern
0      7  [1, 0, 0]
1     10  [1, 0, 1]
```